# How do I populate a text area from items in a db field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a table, let's call it Items, in the db.  It has a field, let's call it `description`.

All I want to do is display all the cell values in `description` in a text area in a view.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify? You want all descriptions from items in a *single* text area, or one text area per description?

Comment: All of the descriptions from items in a single text area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Load just one attribute not a whole model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119167/rails-load-just-one-attribute-not-a-whole-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `Item.pluck()` method. If you do `Item.pluck(:description)` it gives you an array whose elements are the descriptions of each item. (e.g. `["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", ... ]`)

Now your question about displaying these items in a text area needs some clarification, however, from first glance if in your `text_area_tag` you have `value:descriptions.join("\n")` where `descriptions` is an array created by the `pluck()` method.